# Cypress- can't record test

Tags: automation

Can anyone help me with test recording in Cypress?!?!?
I can not record the test and tried all the possible ways that are on the internet. I always get this error "'cypress' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I'm using Windows 10 PRO.